Cross-platform Jetpack Compose project in Android Studio on Ubuntu cannot detect webdriver or desktop
Cross-platform Jetpack Compose project in Android Studio on Ubuntu cannot detect webdriver or desktop on available devices to run the app

Usually on Windows, Android Studio quickly detects a web driver and desktop for run apps on these devices. But on Ubuntu, this is not the case.
I tried to install the chrome driver through SDK manager, but it didn’t help.

